# How do I sum the differences between a complete predicted ratings array and actual known ratings (python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, difference

basically I generated a complete array of predicted ratings using a bunch of training ratings. Separate from this training ratings database I have a second non-overlapping database which contains more ratings that were not known at the time of training, but that predictions now exist for.

I want to compare the generated predicted ratings against the actual ratings inside of my test database.

For example, inside my test database might be:

```
user ID, item ID, rating, timestamp
1,356,4.0,964980962 
1,500,3.0,964981208
1,593,4.0,964983793
```

Inside of my predicted ratings database are:

```
1,1,rating
1,2,rating
1,3,rating
....
1,355,rating
1,356,**RATING**
1,357,rating
```

So from the above two text files i want to compare the real and generated ratings for user 1, item 356, user 1 item 500, etc. all through all users and items that are present in both.

I actually already coded something which did this for me last year and don't remember exactly what I did. I remember I had to load both in to memory and then there was a super succinct easy way where I summed the differences in a nested loop structure.

Comment: Can you share the expected output ?

Comment: really I want to calculate the RMSE, so for example if there are 5 ratings and 4 are right and one is off by -2, the error would be ((-2)^2)^0.5) = 2